# Money Counting Machine

Tags: robotics

At the moment I want to build a machine that counts money (money counter machine). When the user puts in the money bills, it will scan them, count them and send the results to a program running on a PC.

I really don't know the kind of hardware I need to build this machine. I have been googling for a while but can't seem to find any place that will give me a good answer.

I will also create a software that will receive the counting from the machine. Creating the software is not a problem. What I need now is how to build this machine and where to get the hardware.

My main concern now is which hardware do I need to create this machine and probably where to get it.

If I decide to buy an existing machine without building it myself, is it possible to create one software that will work with any machine or do I have to write the software for each particular machine I may choose (in case I change the machine later).

Where can I buy an existing machine?

Comment: Are you needing to do counterfeit detection also?

Comment: At the moment not really but i welcome that idea also. If you have any idea, then kindly let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eBay has a bunch of [bill counters](http://shop.ebay.com/?_nkw=bill+counter) currently listed.  If you just need one (rather than needing an OEM part so you can design something for production), this may be a good source.

Comment: I want i bill counter i can develop a software for it to process the counting information it receives from the counter.

Comment: @kap, some of the bill counters listed there may have external interfaces -- you'd have to look at the descriptions.  Or you could tear a used one apart and just use the bill counting mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I found a bill counter (only worked with 1 dollar bills) that communicated over a simple serial connection from an electronic salvage place in Tacoma, WA. I got the basic communication to work but something appeared damaged as it simply would not scan bills correctly. Probably explains why it was at a salvage place.

The manufacturer had a simple protocol doc that listed the expected responses, time intervals, etc. It seemed very straightforward.

I can't recall the model number or any details but I'll see if I can dig it up and post it here.

UPDATE: Didn't read the original request very clearly. The thing I found is technically a "bill validator" or "bill accepter" -- i.e. it's used for vending machines to input money so it's not designed for speedy counting. It's made by iCT, model BL-700R-USD4P2. Still can't find the PDF with protocol details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I'm looking forward to hear from you again.